# TFS 2010 - Project Creation Fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server, ssrs

I am trying to create a new Project and I get the following Error:

---

**Error**
Insufficient Permissions to create a new SQL Server Report Services at mytfserver\DefaultCollection.

**Explanation**
The permissions granted your user name and ID on the SQL Server Reporting Services at mytfserver\DefaultCollection do not allow you create a new project.  You must be granted specific permissions by the server administrator.

**User Action**
Contact the Administrator for the SQL Server Reporting Services at mytfserver\DefaultCollection and ask that the permission "Content Manager" be added to your user Account.

---

I have checked and double checked.  I have given my user all the permissions possible on my Reporting services (Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder, TFS Content Manager).  I have also made my user a "System Administrator" for my Reporting Services.

My user is a member of MyDomain\Domain Admins and I have made that group and my user a local admin on the server and members of the TFS Administrators group.  I have also added them to admin the share point services (though that seems to be working alright).

**Configuration** 
Running Win 2008 SP2: Installed apps: SQL 2008, SCVMM (R1)
   Hosting: Win 2008 SP2: Installed apps: SQL 2008, TFS 2010 (and dependent items)
   Hosting: Windows 7 Ultimate: Installed Apps: Visual Studio Team Suite 2010 (And dependant items)
Everything has been freshly installed in the last 48 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as this is a question about TFS 2010 Beta 1, probably best asked [where you did in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprerelease/thread/66af4114-e8aa-4af3-8790-a4e2d94e3dbf) as more Microsoft product group people monitor that and so any problems you find in the beta product will be more likely to be addressed before the final release.

As you are trying to get this together for a Code Camp demo at the weekend, probably the quickest way to solve it would be to install from scratch (including SQL Server 2008).  If you follow the pre-requisite installation instructions carefully then it should work for you - I've installed the beta a few times now using those instructions.

There was [an issue in Beta 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2009/05/18/tfs-2010-beta-1-don-t-run-initial-configuration-from-the-administration-console-mmc.aspx) if you don't go straight into the Project Collection creation part after the install wizard - but that was more related to Sharepoint stuff rather than reporting services permissions.

Good luck for your demo.

Comment: Drivers for Dell Precision M90 and Windows Server 2008 (R1).  PS: I love Radio TFS!